# Prove $\sin((2n+1)x)$ function by induction

Tags: induction

Can someone help me prove the following by mathematical induction:

$$\sin((2n+1)x)=\sin(x)(1+2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} \cos(2kx))$$

I was told to use induction on $n$; however I keep getting stuck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $n=0$, this is trivially true. Suppose $n-1$ is true, let's consider $n$, it suffices to show
$$\sin((2n+1)x)-\sin((2n-1)x)=2\sin(x)\cos(2nx)$$
now do you see how to finish?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: The formula is $\sin(x)-\sin(y)=\color{#C00000}{2}\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)$